# MS Access 2010: "collating sequence not supported with the specified file format"

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I recently upgraded to MS Access 2010. When I open a certain .mdb (2000-2003 file format), I am greeted with this message: `collating sequence not supported with the specified file format`. I'm not sure what it means, but it gives it to me every time the database is opened.

I have Googled around but found nothing that I thought seemed related. If I upgraded the file format to 2007 it didn't give me the message but that isn't much of an option in this situation.

Is this a 2010 issue? or is there something corrupted with my database? What do I need to do to work around it?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4584314/cannot-open-database-created-with-access-2010-in-access-2007-even-with-sp2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/202150) by M$ fixed my problem. The issue was the "new database sort order" setting.

Comment: Link to Microsoft KB is dead

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem and found a different solution.  I am using ms-access 2010 and 2007.  2010 could not create mdb files and the accdb files it created would not open in 2007.  The solution was to go to the File tab in 2010, click the options link and set the sort order for new databases to 'General - legacy'.  The sort order that was displayed was 'General'  I then created a blank database in mdb format and imported all the objects, forms, code et.  The newly rebirthed database works in 2007.

Comment: I ran into this issue using the 'compact and repair' command. This solution worked for me.

Comment: Just FYI I ran into the same problem as @MikeStrother unable to 'compact and repair' in 2022 with Microsoft 365 and this solution still works.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this error after enabling the **Track name AutoCorrect info** option for a database originally created in Access 2007 then later upgraded to the 2010 file format. I'm now using it in Access 2016.

In my case, contrary to the resolution provided by the Microsoft [KB article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/202150/you-receive-a-selected-collating-sequence-not-supported-error-message) referenced by @Icode4food's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3601150/2227908) the solution was to change the new database sort order *to* "General - Legacy".

Additionally, this database is configured to automatically perform a Compact & Repair upon exit.  For some reason this caused the sort order to revert back to General. Therefore the exact steps I had to take to solve the problem are as follows:

1. Change *New database sort order* setting to **General - Legacy**.
2. Close database.  Cancel automatic Compact & Repair by pressing `ESC`.
3. Re-open database and confirm sort is is still set to General - Legacy.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced similar issue, I had MS-Access file created on one machine. And I shifted my web server to another machine. And I started getting the similar exception.

I just created a new MS-Access DB on new machine and copied all the tables (with data) from old db.

And using the new DB file fixed my problem.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Backup. Make a backup copy of the bad database, without overwriting any existing backups. Whatever has gone wrong, you don't want to make it worse, and a backup gives you multiple attempts at recovery.

Uncheck the Name AutoCorrect boxes.

- In Access 2007: Office Button | Access Options | Current Database.
- In previous versions: Tools | Options | General.

For an explanation of why, see Failures caused by Name Auto-Correct.
Compact.

- In Access 2010: Compact and Repair Database on the Database Tools ribbon.
- In Access 2007: Office Button | Manage | Compact/Repair.
- In previous versions: Tools | Database Utilities | Compact/Repair.

Decompile. Close Access, and enter something like this at the command prompt:
Use the path to where msaccess.exe is found on your computer, and include the quotes.

Compact again.

Open Access (holding down the Shift key if you have any startup code), and compact again.

Do this twice: one comp