# Cannot Open Database Created with Access 2010 in Access 2007 Even With SP2

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010

A database created with one of the new sort orders will not open in Access 2007 even with Service Pack 2 (SP2) installed.

Comment: Please explain the down vote. Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a list of compatibility issues : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/cc907897, which includes sort order, however the big gottcha is not stressed, and that is General sort order. This is *not* the same as General sort order in previous versions of Access, it is new. For compatibility, you must choose General Legacy sort order.