# Access Record-Locking Information and Shared Use

Tags: ms-access, networking

So,

I've run into a bit of a problem and I'm wondering how you business users deal with this. 
I have Access Databases on shared drives in secured locations. It has just been set up so that only a couple of users have 'Delete' permissions (because we don't want someone to delete the database). Everyone else, has read, write, etc but NOT delete.

This works fine, but I've noticed that the Record-Locking-Information file is not deleted after the regular users log off the database (I'm sure due to the 'no-delete' permissions for the folder).

What solutions to this problem have you all implemented?

Comment: Is it a problem? It is not essential that the file is deleted.

Comment: I guess that's part of my question. Is there a problem that this file persists even when no one is using the database? And it will never be deleted unless an administrator manually deletes it. EDIT: Also, when I'm developing it, I generally check for the Record Locking Information file first to determine whether it's in use or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Many have suggested that you must give FULL permissions to users, but
>   this is not true. You need only give them MODIFY permissions -- you
>   can deny them DELETE permission, which is a good idea, as it prohibits
>   the users from "accidentally" deleting your data file.
>
> It is true that for a user with DELETE permissions, the LDB file will
>   be deleted on exit when that user is the last user exiting the
>   database. But it is not required that the LDB file be deleted --
>   indeed, in Access 2 and before, the LDB files were not deleted on
>   exit, but just left there hanging around. This generally has no
>   downside, but occasionally the LDB file gets corrupted and causes
>   problems and really does need to be deleted and recreated afresh.
>
> What I do is have two classes of database users (as defined in custom
>   NT security groups specific to my Access application(s)) -- DBAdmins
>   and everyone else. The DBAdmins have FULL permissions, everybody else
>   only CHANGE. The result is that any time a DBAdmin exits as the final
>   user, the LDB is deleted. This setup works really well, and I've been
>   using it for well over a decade.

-- David W Fenton

Comment: Works for me, as long as having the LDB hanging out doesn't generally do any harm.

Comment: Your admins log in reasonably often, I hope, to compact & repair and so forth? So the lock-file will be deleted and recreated reasonably often.

Comment: Yes, we do. It actually created a problem today - For some reason a Compact Repair on an aacdb resulted in Access 2007 users having compatibility issues (db was made in 2010 but has none of the new features implemented) - But that's another issue for another day.

Comment: I'll bet that your sort order is not set to General - Legacy. Change it.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4584314/cannot-open-database-created-with-access-2010-in-access-2007-even-with-sp2