# Selected collating sequence not supported by the operating system. WinXP

Tags: c#, .net, ms-access, windows-xp

I want to get some data from **.mdb** but I get an exception on WinXP machine. There is MDAC 2.8 alrdy installed. Is there way to solve my problem without changing DB type? Method to get data.:

```
private void GetDatafromDB(){
        int counter = 0;
        string _sql = "select * from template where 1=1";
        OleDbDataReader reader = ldb.ReadList(_sql);
                while (reader.Read())
                {

                    if (reader[1] is DBNull)
                        continue;
                     this.t0 = reader[0].ToString();//autoid
                     this.t1 = reader[1].ToString();//real name
                     this.t2 = reader[2].ToString();//userid
                     this.t3 = reader[3].ToString();//fingerindex
                     this.t4 = reader[4].ToString();//rights
                     this.t5 = reader[5].ToString();//base64  template_9


                    //int autoid = (int)reader[0];
                    byte[] tmp = Convert.FromBase64String(this.t5);
                    zkfp2.DBAdd(mDBHandle, Int32.Parse(t3), tmp);
                    counter++;
          }
          textTips.AppendText("Loaded "+ counter +" fingerprints \r\n");
    }
```

Exception:

> ************** Exception Text **************
>
> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: Selected collating sequence not
>   supported by the operating system.    at
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextErrorHandling(OleDbHResult
>   hr)    at
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextForSingleResult(tagDBPARAMS
>   dbParams, Object& executeResult)    at
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandText(Object&
>   executeResult)    at
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommand(CommandBehavior
>   behavior, Object& executeResult)    at
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReaderInternal(CommandBehavior
>   behavior, String method)    at
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
>   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReader()    at
>   WindowsFormsApp1.LocalDb.ReadList(String SQL) in
>   c:\Users\user\Desktop\fingerprint
>   WINxp\WindowsFormsApp1\LocalDb.cs:line 132    at
>   WindowsFormsApp1.Form1.GetDatafromDB() in
>   c:\Users\user\Desktop\fingerprint
>   WINxp\WindowsFormsApp1\Form1.cs:line 362    at
>   WindowsFormsApp1.Form1.connDevice_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in
>   c:\Users\user\Desktop\fingerprint
>   WINxp\WindowsFormsApp1\Form1.cs:line 354    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons
>   button, Int32 clicks)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message&
>   m)    at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32
>   msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)

Comment: Do any of your tables lack a unique key index?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MS Access 2010: "collating sequence not supported with the specified file format"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601107/ms-access-2010-collating-sequence-not-supported-with-the-specified-file-format)

Comment: @JohnWu I have only one table with one unique key index - ID

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that target machine has another system language and .mdb file has been created on another one. Creating new database on target machine - solved my question.

Source - http://www.cnblogs.com/zoupeiyang/archive/2009/03/11/1408741.html